# jQuery issue when hovering over image anchor on top of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am having an issue with some HTML/CSS/jQuery.

```
<div class="project-thumbnail">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
            <span class="project-thumbnail-overlay overlay-color">Random Title</span>
            <img width="270" height="180" src="http://i45.tinypic.com/34fgner.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="zoom-button">
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">
            <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/wme8ev.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

You can see what I am trying to achieve here: http://jsfiddle.net/NrtvK/1/

Basically, most of the functionality works. However, when you hover over the plus icon anchor, it makes the image stutter like madness and it removes the hovered thumbnail state.

I'd like both effects to work in unison, but the plus icon pointing to a separate URL while keeping the hover state even when hovering over it.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NrtvK/3/)

```
$('.portfolio-project').mouseenter(function(e) {    
    $(this).find('.project-thumbnail').children('a')
        .children('img').stop().animate({ height: imgHeight, left: '0', top: '0', width: imgWidth}, 100).end()
        .children('span').stop().fadeIn(200);
    $(this).find('.project-thumbnail').next('.zoom-button').show();
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.project-thumbnail').children('a')
        .children('img').stop().animate({ height: imgHeight + 33, left: '-20', top: '-20', width: imgWidth + 50}, 100).end()
        .children('span').stop().fadeOut(200);
    $(this).find('.project-thumbnail').next('.zoom-button').hide();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. I like this jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

it's because your plus icon is outside the `.project-thumbnail`, which fires on mouseleave. try put it inside the `.project-thumbnail` and tweak your js and css after that.

something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/Em4wh/

Comment: Thanks @bondythegreat. Moving the anchor back into the `.project-thumbnail` seems to cause problems with the CSS. Not in this case, but I have other things that I did not post that get screwed up. Thanks for your solution, it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you move the mouse over the plus icon that triggers your `project-thumbnail` mouse leave handler which hides the plus icon, which in turn triggers the `project-thumbnail` mouse enter handler again which shows the plus icon - but your mouse is already over the plus so that triggers the mouse leave handler again, etc., etc., etc. Of course the stuttering is because of the animations starting and stopping repeatedly.

You could perhaps revise your html structure to put the plus link inside the `project-thumbnail` div - bondythegreat's has you covered there.

Or you could try a hack like this:

```
var projectThumbnail = $('.project-thumbnail'),
        imgWidth = projectThumbnail.width(),
        imgHeight = projectThumbnail.height(),
        timeoutID; // <-- new variable

    projectThumbnail.mouseenter(function(e) {    
        $(this).children('a').children('img').stop().animate({ height: imgHeight, left: '0', top: '0', width: imgWidth}, 100);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').stop().fadeIn(200);
        $(this).next('.zoom-button').show();
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        // move original functionality into a timeout, saving a reference
        // to this for use within the timeout
        var $this = $(this);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
           $this.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({ height: imgHeight + 33, left: '-20', top: '-20', width: imgWidth + 50}, 100);
           $this.children('a').children('span').stop().fadeOut(200);
           $this.next('.zoom-button').hide();
        }, 5);
    });

    // cancel the timeout when entering the plus button
    $(".zoom-button").mouseenter(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NrtvK/2/

(I know this is pretty dodgy, but I tried it out of curiosity and when it worked I figured I might as well post it.)